# Upload multiple files using rest api

Tags: javascript, rest

I am trying to write code to upload multiple files using SP2013 REST API. I referred the MSDN article "[upload single file using REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx)".

But I am having problem when I modified the code to upload multiple files.
I debugged the code and found `addFileToFolder()` function is not getting called.
Can anyone help in figuring out the issue?

**HTML**

```
<input id="getFile" type="file" multiple="multiple"/><br />
<input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="Upload" onclick="upload()"/>
```

**Code**

```
function upload(){
    $.when(uploadFiles()).done(function(){
        alert('all files uploaded');
    });
}
var fileCount = 0;
function uploadFiles() {
    debugger;
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = 'SiteAssets';
    var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');

    var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

    var def = $.Deferred();

    var promises = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < window.document.getElementById('getFile').files.length; i++){
            promises.push(function(){
            var getFile = getFileBuffer(i);
            getFile.done(function(resultArray){
                var addFile = addFileToFolder(resultArray);
                addFile.done();
                addFile.fail(onError);
            });
            getFile.fail(onError);
        });
    }

    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){def.resolve()});

    return def.promise();

    function getFileBuffer(i){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onLoadend = function(e){
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.onError = function(e){
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[i]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    function addFileToFolder(resultArray){
        var i = fileCount;
        if(i == (fileInput[0].files.length - 1)){
            fileCount = 0;
        }
        fileCount++;
        fileName = fileInput[0].files[i].name;
        var fileCollectionEndPoint = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" + 
            "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
            serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName
        );

        return $.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndPoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: resultArray,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest":$("__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length":resultArray.byteLength
            }
        });
    }
}        
// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    a = error;
    alert(error.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Is `addFileToFolder()` not getting called even once? Are you seeing any error alerts?

Comment: No. I also tried putting `alert()` at the beginning of function but it is getting called

Comment: Please be more specific - "No" to which of my two questions? Which function did you put `alert()` at the beginning of? Did you mean "but it is NOT getting called"?

Comment: Neither the `addFileToFolder()` is getting called even once nor I am seeing any error alert. I put `alert()` in the very first line of `addFileToFolder()` function.

Comment: Put an `alert()` before `for(var ...`, before `var getFile ...`, before `getFile.done ...` and before `var addFile ...`. Then you'll know exactly where your problem is.

Comment: All this I already tried. Can you please check if I am using deferred and promise in correct manner or not or is anything missing there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27510/discussion-between-yayati-and-submits).

Comment: When I used the above code, while uploading a file to sharepoint, getting Error " String.format is not a function" . Please let me know what's the resolution for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some how I figured out the way of using deferred and promises in correct manner. Following code runs perfectly as required.

```
function upload() {
    // Define the folder path for this example.
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = 'SiteAssets';

    // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
    var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
    var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();
    var fileCount = fileInput[0].files.length;
    // Get the server URL.
    var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var filesUploaded = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++){
        // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        var getFile = getFileBuffer(i);
        getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer,i) {
    
            // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
            var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer,i);
            addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
                //$("#msg").append("<div>File : "+file.d.Name+" ... uploaded sucessfully</div>");
                filesUploaded++;
                if(fileCount == filesUploaded){
                    alert("All files uploaded successfully");
                    //$("#msg").append("<div>All files uploaded successfully</div>");
                    $("#getFile").value = null;
                    filesUploaded = 0;
                }
            });
            addFile.fail(onError);
        });
        getFile.fail(onError);
    
    }

    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    function getFileBuffer(i) {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result,i);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[i].files[0]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer,i) {
    var index = i;
        
        // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
        var fileName = fileInput[index].files[0].name;

        // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        });
    }
}

// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
}
```

Comment: nice, this helped me a lot! But you should have a look again at your promise pattern for async methods. You are using it the wrong way. You should't use nested async methods. instead linearize it.

Comment: you should also include the reference from where you got the code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx

Comment: Yayati,Your answer is very helpful, could you please let me know how can we insert custom column values along with document upload in document library? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
//For updating custom column while uploading file you use following code with yayati's code

    function upload() {
        // Define the folder path for this example.
        var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = 'SiteAssets';

        // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
        var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
        var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();
        var fileCount = fileInput[0].files.length;
        // Get the server URL.
        var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        var filesUploaded = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
            // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
            // Get the local file as an array buffer.
            var getFile = getFileBuffer(i);
            getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer, i) {

                // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
                var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer, i);
                addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
                   //Get ID of File uploaded 
                    var getfileID = getItem(file.d);
                    getfileID.done(function (fResult) {
                        var colObject = new Object();
                        colObject["FileType"] = fileType;
                        var changeItem = updateFileMetadata(libraryName, fResult.d, colObject);
                        changeItem.done(function (result) {
                            filesUploaded++;
                            if (fileCount == filesUploaded) {
                                alert("All files uploaded successfully");
                                //$("#msg").append("<div>All files uploaded successfully</div>");
                                $("#getFile").value = null;
                                filesUploaded = 0;
                            }
                        });
                        changeItem.fail(function (result) {

                        });

                    }, function () { });

                });
                addFile.fail(onError);
            });
            getFile.fail(onError);

        }

        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        function getFileBuffer(i) {
            var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                deferred.resolve(e.target.result, i);
            }
            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                deferred.reject(e.target.error);
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[i]);
            return deferred.promise();
        }

        // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
        function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer, i) {
            var index = i;

            // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
            var fileName = fileInput[0].files[index].name;

            // Construct the endpoint.
            var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                    "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                    "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                    serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

            // Send the request and return the response.
            // This call returns the SharePoint file.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
                type: "POST",
                data: arrayBuffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Display error messages. 
    function onError(error) {
        alert(error.responseText);
    }

    function updateFileMetadata(libraryName, item, colPropObject) {
        var def = jQuery.Deferred();

        var restSource = siteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('" + libraryName + "')/Items(" + item.Id + ")";
        var jsonString = "";

        var metadataColumn = new Object();
        metadataColumn["type"] = item.__metadata.type;
        //columnArray.push(metadataColumn);
        if (colPropObject == null || colPropObject == 'undefined')// For library having no column properties to be updated
        {
            colPropObject = new Object();
        }
        colPropObject["__metadata"] = metadataColumn;
        jsonString = JSON.stringify(colPropObject);
        var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            'url': restSource,
            'method': 'POST',
            'data': jsonString,
            'headers':
                {
                    'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                    'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                    'X-RequestDigest': jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                    "IF-MATCH": item.__metadata.etag,
                    "X-Http-Method": "MERGE"
                },
            'success': function (data) {
                var d = data;
                dfd.resolve(d);
            },
            'error': function (err) {
                dfd.reject(err);
            }
        });

        return dfd.promise();
    }
/*=====================================================
Get Item for Uploaded Document
=======================================================*/
    function getItem(file) {
        var def = jQuery.Deferred();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: file.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                def.resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (data, arg, jhr) {
                def.reject(data, arg, jhr);
            }
        });
        return def.promise();
        //return call;
    }
```