# How to attach multiple documents to a SharePoint list Item using REST Api

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api

Hi I am trying to attach documents to a SharePoint list item using REST Api, but am getting an 404 error while performing. PFB my code:

```
function AddAttachments()
{   
    var digest = "";
    $.ajax(
    {
                    url: "/_api/contextinfo",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                                    "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                    digest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                    }
    }).done(function() {
                    var fileInput = $('#uploadFile');
                    var fileName = fileInput[0].files[0].name;
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var fileData = e.target.result;
                        var res11 = $.ajax(
                        {                             
                                        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + fileName + "')",                                       
                                        method: "POST",
                                        binaryStringRequestBody: true,
                                        data: fileData,
                                        processData: false,
                                        headers: {
                                                        "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose",          
                                                        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                                                        "content-length": fileData.byteLength
                                        },                                                                                                                            
                                        success: function (data) {                                            
                                                console.log("success");                                               
                                        },
                                        error: function (data) {                                                
                                                console.log("Error occured." + data.responseText);
                                        }
                        });                          
                    };
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);

    });                                          
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the issue with multiple files uploads or even for single file its not working?

Comment: Multiple Files...Am able to upload single file but not multiple

Comment: Just need to know how to iterate through multiple files

Comment: check this answer https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/154641/8068 and modify according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through files as below

```
var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files; 
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        //Logic to attach in SharePoint goes here
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

Comment: How to get each file name from it?

Comment: `var fileName = f.name;`

Comment: Able to add only one attachment..For second attachment it is throwing 409 conflict error

Comment: Conflict is happening because your ajax call is async - make it synchronous by adding `async:false`

Comment: Not working...400 Bad Request error