# REST API: upload a file to a Docset

Tags: rest, file-upload, document-set, api

Similar to this ([Upload multiple files using rest api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154472/upload-multiple-files-using-rest-api)) I want to upload files to an existing Docset. I am using the pure REST API as I am on Java.

I asked myself, how to control where the uploaded file should go - currently it's going to the "root" of my list.

Sorry if my wording is maybe misleading, but I am not a Sharepoint user or developer - I just have to connect to it with another app.

The upload URL I am using looks like this:

`_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(''{0}'')/files/add(overwrite=true,url=''{2}'')?$expand=ListItemAllFields`

Where it oviously starts with my host and website etc. and the placeholders being replaced with

- the server's relative URL I got before after I created the DocSet (0)
- the file name of the uploaded element (2)

I thought I can control the target DocSet by adding to the URL right after (0) OR before the /files part - both lead to an error that says that this is an unknown resource.

Maybe there is a different approach to control the target DocSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Document Set is, in essence, a folder, so the value you need for `getfolderbyserverrelativeurl` is the server relative URL to the document set itself.

If your document set is in the root of a document library, that would be something like

```
'/sites/YourSite/Your Library/Your Doc Set'
```

That all needs to be in your `{0}` replacement value.  You don't need to add anything else to the URL.

Comment: When I do so, it looks like this:
`_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/websites/A0000023/TaskItLibrary/ne+mail+mit+zeug+und+so')/files/add(overwrite=true,url='OBUE-C7WHED_f.eml')?$expand=ListItemAllFields'` - I have to encode the DocSet's name, otherwise I get "illegal characters" exception. With this URL I also get an error which says:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException - File not found

Comment: If you know the list item ID of the Doc Set's list item, you can get what SharePoint expects the relative URL to be by getting `/_api/web/list/getbytitle('Your Library')/items(itemID)/Folder?$select=ServerRelativeUrl`, that might help?

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly like I commented before: `/websites/A0000023/TaskItLibrary/ne+mail+mit+zeug+und+so` but this does not work.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what to tell you then.

Comment: My problem was the wrong URL enconding, so it seems that you cannot use a "+" as a space instead of "%20" - so I had to change the encoding...